# Python - def findLine(prog, target)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been presented with the following problem:

Define a function findLine(prog, target) to perform the following. Assume prog is a list of   strings containing a BASIC program, like the type generated by getBASIC(); assume target is a   string containing a line number, which is the target of a GOTO statement. The function should   return the index i (a number between 0 and len(prog)-1) such that prog[i] is the line whose   label equals target.

Sample input/output: If you call
findLine(['10 GOTO 20','20 END'], '10')
then the output should be 0, since item 0 of the list is the line with label 10.

Here is my code:

```
    def findLine(prog, target):
   for l in range(0, len(prog)-1):
      progX = prog[l].split()
      for i in range(0, len(progX)):
         if progX[i] == target:
            ans = progX[i]
   return prog.index(ans)
```

As you can tell from the code, I am close to finishing (at least I think I am), but I've become rather stuck with this.  However, I don't know how to identify which index in prog contains the string in progX. Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Also, I know this code isn't as efficient or neat as it could be, but right now I just need it to work.

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: I kindly suggest you change the title as I'm guessing that it gives off the wrong "vibe" and hence may attract downvotes.

Comment: @bernie What would you suggest?  I tried thinking of a title initially but gave up.

Comment: I suggest you identify the problem you're having and then create a small example which demonstrates the problem. Upon doing so the title may be more easily formulated. Doing so may also help you get more-direct, higher-quality answers.

Comment: @bernie Basically, what I need to do is find which index in prog contains the string in the list progX.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to replace the inner for loop with this:

```
if progX[0] == target:
   return l
```

That way you're checking whether the line begins with the line number you're looking for.

Comment: findLine(['10 GOTO 20', '20 END'], '20') has wrong type "None" Type, expected Integer is what I get.

Comment: Your `index` call is looking for a line in the program that is the same as `target`, the line number.  There is no such line, so you're getting `None`.

Answer (score 0):

just try the following code, it works for me.

```
def findLine(prog, target):
   for l in range(0, len(prog)):
     progX = prog[l].split()
     for i in range(0, len(progX)):
          if progX[0] == target:
           return l
```